# Openssl ciphers SHA384 and AEAD

Tags: openssl, hmac, cipher-selection

When running the command: `openssl ciphers -v` I get a long list of cipher combinations. I'm having issues interpreting some of them. An example is:

`DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD`

I thought the last part of the combination, in this case `SHA384` would be the HMAC function. It seems it's been replaced by `AEAD` instead. Reading up on Authenticated Encryption with Associated Data (AEAD) it seems to be a class of block cipher modes, not a specific HMAC function.

Could someone explain this further? Is SHA384 one of these modes? Is SHA384 used in the AES encryption somehow and then that algorithm re-used for the MAC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly(?) duplicate of [What's the hash for in ECDHE-RSA-AES-GCM-SHA?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39590/whats-the-hash-for-in-ecdhe-rsa-aes-gcm-sha)

TLSv1.2 adds a new class of ciphers using AEAD modes such as GCM, which is a single crypto operation that does both encryption and integrity protection, instead of having separate encryption and HMAC e.g. AES128-CBC plus HMAC-SHA1. Mac=AEAD means really no HMAC is needed because of AEAD. However, TLSv1.2 also changes the PRF (key derivation) to use varying SHA-2 hashes (instead of always SHA-1 and MD5) so the hash is still specified in the ciphersuite.